# boost::asio::ssl::context::add_verify_path

Tags: c++, boost, ssl, openssl, boost-asio

I wish to verify a server's certificate. I have a boost::asio::ssl::context

This successfully verifies the certificate:

```
context.load_verify_file("E:\\a\\windows\\Path\\to\\certificate\\9207bca9.0");
```

However, I do not wish to explicitly specify the files to verify certificates against. I want to be able to put them in one directory, and tell the context to use the files in that folder to verify the certificates. So I do this instead:

```
context.add_verify_path("E:\\a\\windows\\Path\\to\\certificate");
```

And verification is unsuccessful

Note: The file name 9207bca9.0: 9207bca9 is the hash of the subject of the CA certificate, and its extension is '.0' to satisfy the requirements of the add_verify_path method found here (also the only contents of this file are the root certificate. Keep in mind I have been successful in verifying certificates with this file):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__context/add_verify_path/overload1.html

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear from the question what the actual problem is. "So I do this instead" -- and then what?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? What happens when you check a root server  with an "quasi-official" pem like this one: http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem . It has multiple certificates in a single file and worked for me under windows (openssl 1.0.1p and ctx.load_verify_file(..))

Answer (score 3):

There are only two possibilities that I can think of, the first is that your hash value is incorrect, this can be verified like so:

```
openssl x509 -noout -hash -in ca-certificate-file
```

The second is that there is some error in your directory configuration preventing OpenSSL from using the CA directory, for example, permissions and ownership are important on Linux systems, not sure to what extent these matter on Windows platforms. The only way to pinpoint this sort of error is to trace the verification stage via a debugger and observe the code directly as it scans the directory.